# Proof that OLS regression with intercept only is equal to mean of dependent variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, least-squares

One property of ordinary least square regression (OLS) is that a regression of some (dependent) variable $y$ on an intercept only yields the arithmetic mean
$\bar y$. The advantage is that it is easy to derive standard errors, confidence bands etc using OLS.

**The OLS model (intercept only) can be written as:**

$$y_i=\beta_0 + u_i,$$

with error term $u_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,\sigma^{2})$. The result would be that
$\beta_0 = \bar y$.

**Easy to show in R:**

```
y= c(1,2,3)

lm(y~1)
Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
          2  

mean(y)
[1] 2
```

**I wonder how to write down this property in a proof-like manner!**

My take would be to take expectations:

$$ E(y_i)=E(\beta_0 + u_i). $$

Since $E(u_i)=0$ (per assumption), we get

$$ E(y_i)=\beta_0. $$

- Is this the full story or do I miss something here?

Comment: You can do this easily yourself: 1. Write down the formula for the squared error, depending on your estimate $\theta$ 2. find the minimum of this expression by setting the first derivative to 0 and checking that the second derivative is >0

Comment: Also you dont need any expectations if you want to prove that the OLS-estimate with only an intercept corresponds to the sample mean. You only need to show that the values coincide for an arbitrary sample

Comment: do you have any updates? I recently have trouble with this proof too!

Answer (score 1):

The question is ill-posed.  The OP clearly confused *estimates* with *parameters* (as well as *sample statistics* with *population characteristics*).  In addition, OLS is not a "model" but a parameter estimation method.  That said, the correct form of this question may be stated as follows:

> *Suppose a sample $\{y_1, \ldots, y_n\}$ is drawn from the intercept-only linear model
> \begin{align}
> y = \beta_0 + u, \quad u \sim N(0, \sigma^2).
> \end{align}
> Show that the OLS estimate of the parameter $\beta_0$, denoted by $\hat{\beta}_0$, is equal to the sample mean
> $$\bar{y} = \frac{1}{n}(y_1 + \cdots + y_n).$$*

The proof is immediate, if you know that the OLS estimate $\hat{\beta}$ of $\beta$ in the general linear model (in matrix form): $y = X\beta + u$, where $y \in \mathbb{R}^n, X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is of full column rank, [has a closed-form solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation)
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty. \tag{1}
\end{align}

For the intercept-only model, $y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & \cdots & y_n \end{bmatrix}^T$, $X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$, substituting them into $(1)$ yields
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta}_0 = \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix} = n^{-1}\sum_{i = 1}^ny_i = \bar{y}.
\end{align}
This completes the proof.

Using the same expression $(1)$, this result can be slightly generalized: suppose that, in addition to the intercept, you also have $p$ predictors $x_1, \ldots, x_p$.   If all these observed predictor vectors are centered, in the sense that $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_{ij} = 0, j = 1, \ldots, p$, then $\hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y}$ still holds.  For a detailed proof, refer to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311503/show-that-hat-beta-0-bary-for-ols-when-the-columns-of-mathbfx-are/311518#311518).